# Getting a "Yaml file not found" error when trying to run cardano-node

Tags: cardano-node

Following the instructions here on running cardano-node:
https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/running-cardano

I'm running into an error on startup that looks like this:
`InvalidYaml (Just (YamlException "Yaml file not found: /path/to/testnet/testnet-config.json"))`

Do the configuration files have to be Yaml formatted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON is a proper subset of YAML, so JSON is okay. Are you using the standard testnet config downloaded from [here](https://hydra.iohk.io/build/5822084/download/1/index.html)? It is best to wget it.

Comment: My stupid mistake, I didn't check the json files and they're improperly formatted.  Thank you!